# In this Kerbal Space Program tutorial, why does the commentator put the Stayputnik module on top of the crew capsule?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I have been watching Scott Manley's KSP tutorials, specifically [this one here](https://youtu.be/WpA1V5_-MUU?t=15m30s). He intentionally strands a Kerbal in orbit, then shows how to build a "rescue rocket", but doesn't go very in depth on the latter. I have pasted the video at the point where he begins talking about the rescue rocket, but I don't understand why he attaches the Stayputnik probe to the top of the command capsule? What purpose does this serve for a rescue mission?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using a stayputnik or other drone module along with a kerbal command capsule means the rocket can be remotely piloted without a kerbal in the capsule at launch.

This way, you can remove your pilot before launch, and the stranded kerbal can get into the empty command capsule to return home.

Comment: More specifically, the part of the video that is linked to is about setting up a rocket for recovering a kerbal that is stranded in orbit.  You need a place for that kerbal to sit, and instead of adding a second command pod (or bigger command pod if one were available), the best option in this case is to use a probe core.